# How to compare array list value with previous value and avoid IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have some Selenium tests written with Java, where I loop through Array List object, where I try to input calculation input data for each UI element based on these rules:

- For list index 0 I have to check all elements, but only input their value to UI element if it is not empty.
- For all other indexes I need to check each element, but only input their value to UI element if the value has changed from previous value even if it is empty (and previous was not).

So I have a loop:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < testDataML.size(); i++) {
            ...
            inputMLData(i);
            CommonMethods.clickCalculate(path, outputPath, i);
            ...
    }
```

And then in function inputMLData we have these blocks repeating for each UI element:

```
        if (i == 0) {
            if (!testDataML.get(i).In_VersionID.isEmpty())
                setInputElementPathML(false, "VersionID", testDataML.get(i).In_VersionID);
        } else if (!testDataML.get(i).In_VersionID.equals(testDataML.get(i - 1).In_VersionID))
            setInputElementPathML(false, "VersionID", testDataML.get(i).In_VersionID);
```

And this logic is currently working based on those two points I wrote before. But basically I have to have two conditions - *if (i==0)* and then use *else if* to avoid getting IndexOutOfBoundException on first loop iteration. And after both conditions I am calling identical functions.
So the question is how could I avoid that Exeception? I don't want to use try block, since it would lead to basically the same amount of code. And the whole if logic I could move to another function, but I will have to still provide that function the parameter testDataML.get(i - 1).In_VersionID

Comment: Something like this `testDataML.get( (i ==0)? i : i-1).In_VersionID` ?

Comment: How about starting the loop at 1 - so there is a previous?  And if you need to do the 0 case just do it before the loop - making sure there is at least 1..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from comments: `testDataML.get( (i ==0)? i : i-1).In_VersionID`.
End result in inputMLData looks like this:

```
if (CommonMethods.isNewInput(testDataML.get(i).In_VersionID, testDataML.get((i ==0)? i : i-1).In_VersionID, i, false)) {
            setInputElementPathML(false, "VersionID", testDataML.get(i).In_VersionID);
        }
```

And isNewInput now looks like this:

public static boolean isNewInput (String currentValue, String previousValue, int i, boolean ignoreCase) {
boolean result = false;

```
if (i==0&&!currentValue.isEmpty()) {
    return true;
}

if (ignoreCase) {
    if (!currentValue.equalsIgnoreCase(previousValue)) {
        result = true;
    }
}
else {
    if (!currentValue.equals(previousValue)) {
        result = true;
    }
}
return result;
```

}